Movie about two orphans
I saw this movie when I was young wherein two orphans, a brother and his sister maybe, have some kind of powers or they are just very smart. 
Their parents died in a car accident and they came to know of it in a broken down house's letter box (through a letter off course) at the ending of the movie.
The orphans had been waiting a long time for their parents to return. The letter telling of their death came way late. 
Also there is some scene maybe at a dock of great importance, again it's a maybe.
The movie was definitely a Hollywood movie and most of the movie was shot under cloud cover, like the Twilight series.

Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

Not knowing the time frame, and I don't recall a 'letter', but could that possibly be Escape to Witch Mountain (1975) ?

Two mysterious orphan children have extraordinary powers and are
  chased by a scheming millionaire. But where do these kids really call
  home?

There was also a made for TV remake in 1995, as well as recent remake called 'Race to Witch Mountain in 2009'

Sorry but this isn't the movie. Thanks for the help though

I'm thinking you might be remembering Lemony Snicket's A Series of Unfortunate Events starring Jim Carrey, Liam Aiken, Emily Browning, Timothy Spall, Catherine O'Hara, Billy Connolly, Cedric the Entertainer, Luis Guzmán, Jennifer Coolidge, Meryl Streep, and Jude Law.
The series revolves around three orphans (as opposed to the two you remember, but one is a baby and might have been forgotten) trying to survive while Count Olaf is after their inheritance.  The two older orphans, Violet and Klaus, are very smart.  I don't remember a dock scene specifically, but a rather large part of the movie takes place around a large lake.
Also at the end of the movie they receive a lost letter from their parents.
Wikipedia

... 
Mr. Poe leaves them with their Aunt Josephine, a kindly woman who
  is nonetheless obsessed with grammar and has irrational fears. Olaf
  appears disguised as Captain Sham to interfere with their plans again.
  One day, Josephine is not at the house, claiming to have run away with
  Sham; Klaus takes advantage of her grammar skills to decode her
  location; Curdled Cave. A hurricane sweeps through the town,
  ultimately destroying the house but allowing the children to flee
  before the structure falls apart. They sail to the cave and rescue
  her, but attract leeches due to Josephine having eaten a banana. Olaf
  appears and takes the kids with him, throwing Josephine off the boat
  and to the Lachrymose Leeches after she corrects his speech. 
...
Violet, Klaus and Sunny are allowed to visit their old home one last
  time. A letter lost in the mail finally arrives, and inside is a
  spyglass announcing their family's secret society. Though their future
  is unclear, despite the children's misfortune, they still had each
  other thus making them "Very Fortunate Indeed".


yup, this is the movie. Thanks for the help

@IqbalpreetSingh awesome!  don't forget that you can accept this as the correct answer!  it gives me some more reputation as a reward for helping you and it also helps signal to those that read this question later on that this was the correct answer

This should be accepted as the correct answer.
